# how to force a Rails model to get a new version in a callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two classes, an `Item` and a `Price`. I have a cached hash representation of the `Item` object that I want to clear / create when it is updated, or when an associated object is updated.

In my `Item` class, I have:

In item.rb:

```
  before_update do
    self.create_new_frags
  end
```

However, Rails thinks it has the most recent version and thus the price value doesn't get updated. I tried doing self.reload but it is still not working. How would I tell this instance that it needs to reload it's associations? It's a bit tricky because I can't have it reload everything as this is in a before_update such that I would lose things that are about to be updated.

In item.rb:

```
  def as_mig_hash type # part of create_new_frags
    self.reload  # didn't do anything
    r={}
    r[:id]=id
    r[:header]=header
    r[:detail]=detail
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `reload` affects attributes only. If you want to reload an association, you need to call `reload` on the association directly.

```
<association>.reload
```

Comment: cool, I think you're right, still working through it. in my spec, I was doing it as a `item.price.save` rather than `item.save` - when I switched to the latter, it worked (guessing that there's a touch on item since it is `accepts_nested_attributes_for :price` ). it's odd because I kinda want to pull accepts_nested_attributes_for from my models because of possible security leaks. It's a Rails 3.2.19 app not 4*. Thinking through it, I really need a way to just `touch` the item object without it causing an infinite loop

Comment: @timpone Did you figure it out? Just curious.